# SQL join tables, null values if no link

Tags: sql

I've seen similar questions to this below, but am a little stuck solving.

I have 2 tables - 1 table: 'user_watch_list' which includes a 'movie_id'
the second table: 'streaming' which contains a 'movie_id'.

Structure and example data:

Table: user_watch_list

```
user_id, movie_id  
1 | 1  
1 | 2  
1 | 3  
1 | 4
```

Table: streaming

```
movie_id, channel
1 | SKY
1 | NOW TV
2 | SKY
3 | SKY
```

I'd like the output to show unique movie IDs and a count of how many time it appears in the streaming table.

These two IDs

I'd like the output to show unique movie IDs and a count of how many time it appears in the streaming table.

This is the process and what I have tried.

This will show all movies within user watch lists.

```
$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM user_watch_lists ';
$where = ' WHERE user_id ='.$loggedUser. ' ORDER BY updated_at DESC ';
```

this is showing only what is on the streaming table for that user.

```
$select = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_watch_lists.movie_id FROM user_watch_lists';
$from = '  INNER JOIN streaming ON streaming.movie_id= user_watch_lists.movie_id ';
$where = ' WHERE user_watch_lists.user_id ='.$loggedUser. '  ORDER BY updated_at DESC ';
```

I'd like the output to show unique movie IDs and a count of how many time it appears in the streaming table.

Example for user_id = 1

```
movie_id, count 
1         2 
2         1 
3         1 
4         0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all from one table and COUNT from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984222/get-all-from-one-table-and-count-from-another)

Comment: @nathan You might want to accept the answer of @GordonLinoff which is superior to mine. It works because `count(<attribute_name>)` only count non-null values. Thus a simple left join is enough if you count on the `movie_id` column coming from the joined table (`streaming`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Applying the count function to the column `movie_id` of `streaming` allows for using a simple left join. That works since count skips over null values. Counting the whole record (`count(*)`) would produce wrong results. See [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kAxYo3Z4o3qFhmN7SXj7bT/1) for illustration.

So **adopting the answer by GordonLinoff** (which should be the accepted one) **is recommended**.

---

### Original

Use a left join to relate the `streaming` records to the movie items from the `users` table, adding a synthetic flag to count.

```
      select base.movie_id
           , sum(to_count)   items
        from (
                      select u.movie_id
                           , case when s.movie_id is null then 0 else 1 end to_count 
                        from users     u
                   left join streaming s
                          on s.movie_id = u.movie_id
                       where u.user_id = 1
             ) base
    group by base.movie_id
    order by movie_id
           ;
```

(note that the user_id needs to be replaced in your setting. Best do that with a host variable and *not* by string manipulation for security reasons).

With this approach you need the counting flag (or a similar device to the same purpose) for a left join produces at least 1 record for every record of the firstmost table. If it happens that there is no record from the second table that   meets the join condition, the fields stemming from hat table are null in the result set.
   When grouping and counting you thus have to distinguish between the case that no match or exactly 1 match was found in joining the tables.
   The above solution does so by adding a synthetic numeric attribute marking the (`users`) records without a match and grouping the resultset summing over said attribute.

See it on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/223zPPakwn4JXqZFshKZGJ/0) (it is in postgresql [you haven't specified the dbms you are using] but is standard sql)

**Alternative**

Use an inner join to actually count those movies who have a record in `streaming` and complement the result set with synthetic records for all movies that do not exist in `streaming`.

```
      select u.movie_id
           , count(*)   items
        from users     u
        join streaming s
          on s.movie_id = u.movie_id
       where u.user_id = 1
    group by u.movie_id
   union all 
      select u.movie_id
           , 0          items
        from users     u
       where u.user_id = 1
         and not exists (
                 select 1
                   from streaming s
                  where s.movie_id = u.movie_id 
             )
    order by movie_id
           ;
```

(Again, modify the condition on the user)

Fiddle is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ghyz7K1QTPgVQFb3vEonjo/0).

Comment: @nathan . . . These answers seem much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.movie_id, count(*) from streaming a
left join user_watch_list b on a.movie_id = b.movie_id
where user_id = '1'
group by a.movie_id
```

You need a join for the user.id and 'group by' makes all functions like 'count', 'sum', 'avg' etc apply on the field you want.

Comment: That assumes that all movies are represented in the `streaming` table, ie. `streaming` is the master data table for movies.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT user_watch_list.*, count(streaming.movie_id ) AS Count
FROM user_watch_list
left JOIN streaming
ON user_watch_list.movie_id = streaming.movie_id

Comment: Welcome to Sack Overflow. It would be helpful if you explained some details of how this answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for offering answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `left join` and aggregation:

```
select uwl.movie_id, count(s.movie_id)
from user_watch_list uwl left join
     streaming s 
     on s.movie_id = uwl.movie_id and
where uwl.user_id = 1
group by uwl.movie_id
```